# How to provide a few endpoints for one interaction in pact PHP?

Tags: php, pact

Imagine situation where I have a real client which I want to use in my consumer unit test, and this client is making two requests in background.

Like:

```
$service = new \TestClient($config->getBaseUri());
$serviceResponse = $service->getUserDataById(1);
```

And `getUserDataById` method is sending two calls to provider before returning user data

```
GET  someprovider/v1/username/{id}
GET  someprovider/v1/email/{id}
```

and if I want to use this client in unit test I need to mock both endpoints

How to do this in one interaction?
Example with one consumer response https://github.com/mattermack/pact-php-example/blob/master/example-one/test/ExampleOneMeetupAPIClientTest.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try registering two interactions within 1 unit test
For example:

```
$interaction1 = new InteractionBuilder(config);
$interaction2 = new InteractionBuilder(config);
$consumerRequest1 = new ConsumerRequest();
$consumerRequest1
   ->setPath('someprovider/v1/username/{id}');
$providerResponse1 = new ProviderResponse();
$providerResponse1
     ->setBody(/* body here */);

$interaction1
    ->uponReceiving('request to /someprovider/v1/username/{id}')
    ->with($consumerRequest1)
    ->willRespondWith($providerResponse1);
```

And same for second interaction

Then you can call the

```
$service = new \TestClient($config->getBaseUri());
$serviceResponse = $service->getUserDataById(1);
```

It will hit both endpoints and trigger both interactions. 
At least that what I have done in my tests